# Braintree PHP SDK class names confusions

Tags: php, braintree, class-names

I have started using Braintree php sdk by requiring it via composer. It is working fine. It has classes like:

`Braintree_Configuration`, `Braintree_ClientToken` etc.

However, I was looking into the source code in `vendor/braintree` and I could not find those classes in there, but I did find classes `Configuration` and `ClientToken`.

How is that setup to work?